# what are the best options in embedding power app in SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, powerapp, powerapps-canvas, iframe

I have been playing around how to best embed power apps to look nice on SharePoint pages but have had no luck so far.

When I embed it using any of this ways below (I get all sort of grayish borders around it and it looks ugly)

I have used the below:

```
<iframe src="XXX" width="350" height="450" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>

<iframe width="1024px" height="768px" src="https://web.powerapps.com/webplayer/iframeapp?source=iframe&screenColor=rgba(104,101,171,1)&appId=/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apps/[AppID]" />
```

[image]

Any suggestions or better ways? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few options to add your Power App to SharePoint site pages:

1. You can use SharePoint out of the box Power Apps web part. You have to provide App web link or ID in the web part settings:

   **Documentation**: [Use the Power Apps web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-power-apps-web-part-6285f05e-e441-408a-99d7-aa688195cd1c)

   [image]
2. You can use Enhanced Power Apps web part developed using SPFx and made available to SPFx samples gallery. This sample web part shows how to embed a Power App that resizes, adapts to themes, and supports dynamic properties

   **Reference**: [Enhanced Power Apps web part](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-enhanced-powerapps)

   [image]

Comment: Thanks Ganesh will give the custom webpart a shot

Comment: Sure, any issues while using SharePoint out of the box Power Apps web part?

Comment: Yes I get all sort of greyish borders around it and it looks ugly

Comment: ok, let me know how it goes with custom web part.

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Comment: Thanks  
RaytheonXie-MSFT but the issue is the same.
Can you propose the best way to embed Power BI on SharePoint sites

Comment: You want to embed Power BI or Power Apps?

Comment: Yes Ganesh.Please read my intial post

Comment: In your initial post (question), you asked about embedding **Power App** in SharePoint page and in your above comment (on July 25) you mentioned about embedding **Power BI** on SharePoint sites. So, I just wanted to clarify the exact requirements.

Comment: Hi @naijacoder, does this answer help you in any way? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Comment: Hi @naijacoder, any update on this thread?

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerApps webpart but change settings and disable "Scale to fit" property. That will remove that horrible grey background

Comment: Thanks Fernando I willtry it out